ScrollableTabRow Maintain Tab Always Center
I'm working with a ScrollableTabRow in Jetpack Compose and I want to ensure that the selected tab is always centered horizontally within the ScrollableTabRow, even when scrolling. The ScrollableTabRow itself should be scrollable if there are too many tabs, and the selected tab should always be in the center of the screen when it’s selected.
Note: Even the first item must be centered as well.
@Composable
fun BoxScope.ActionControls() {
    val context = LocalContext.current


    // List of tabs
    val tabs = listOf("Photo", "Video", "Portrait", "Night Mode")

    // State for Pager and ScrollableTabRow
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = { tabs.size })


    // Get a coroutine scope to launch scrolling actions
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()




    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {

        ScrollableTabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
            edgePadding = 0.dp,
            containerColor = Color.Transparent,
            divider = {},
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), // Here, we bind scrollState to the tab row
            indicator = { tabPositions ->
                TabRowDefaults.SecondaryIndicator(
                    Modifier.tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[pagerState.currentPage]),
                    height=2.dp,
                    color = Color.Yellow)
            }

        ) {
            tabs.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                Tab(
                    selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                    selectedContentColor = Color.Yellow,
                    unselectedContentColor = Color.White,
                    onClick = {
                        // Launch a coroutine to animate the scroll to the position
                        scope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)

                        }
                    },
                    text = {
                        Text(text = title)
                    }
                )
            }
        }


        // HorizontalPager for the swipeable content
        HorizontalPager(state = pagerState,
            pageSize = PageSize.Fill,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 16.dp)
            ) { page ->

            when(page){
                0->{

                    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                        ){

                        Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                            ) {

                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .size(60.dp) // Outer circle size (border area)
                                    .border(
                                        width = 1.dp, // Border thickness
                                        color = Color.White, // Border color
                                        shape = CircleShape
                                    )
                            ) {

                            }

                        }
                        Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center){
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .size(80.dp) // Outer circle size (border area)
                                    .border(
                                        width = 2.dp, // Border thickness
                                        color = Color.White, // Border color
                                        shape = CircleShape
                                    )
                            ) {
                                // Circular Button to capture photo with a white-filled circle and border gap
                                Box(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .align(Alignment.Center)
                                        .padding(8.dp)
                                        .size(70.dp) // Size of the circle
                                        .background(
                                            color = Color.White,
                                            shape = CircleShape
                                        )
                                        .clickable {
                                        
                                        },
                                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                                ) {
                              
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {

                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .size(40.dp) // Outer circle size (border area)
                                    .border(
                                        width = 1.dp, // Border thickness
                                        color = Color.White, // Border color
                                        shape = CircleShape
                                    ).padding(8.dp)
                            ) {

                                IconButton({}) {
                                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Cameraswitch, contentDescription = null)
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                else->{

                    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                    ){
                       
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
}


